# Coldfusion Order on alphabet

Tags: loops, coldfusion, iteration, cfloop

I'm looping over an iteration like this :

```
<cfloop condition="depFeedIterator.hasNext()">
    <cfset item=depFeedIterator.next()/>
    <ul><li>#item.getValue('title')</li></ul>
</cfloop>
```

This returns me all the titles. But I have to organize these titles on alphabetic order ( this has been done in the bean itself ). So I've added this:

```
<cfif #left(#item.getValue('title')#,1)# == "a">
    <li><h2>A</h2></li>
       etc
```

But if I have two titles starting with an A i get this:

**A**
Abc

**A**
Aab

instead of :

**A**
Abc
Aac

I've been playing with this a while and couldnt figure it out. I hope you guys have some advise

Comment: `<ul><li>#item.getValue('title')</li></ul>` seems to be missing a `#`.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Ah sorry missed that one, it is correct in my code.

Comment: Why so many `#` in `<cfif #left(#item.getValue('title')#,1)# == "a">
`? `<cfif left(item.getValue('title'),1) == "a">` would be more efficient.

Comment: You should [edit] it here, too, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to track the previous letter too, and only output the heading when the current letter is different from the previous one, eg:

```
<cfset prevFirstLetter = "">
<cfloop condition="depFeedIterator.hasNext()">
    <cfset item=depFeedIterator.next()/>
    <cfset itemTitle = item.getValue('title')>
    <cfset currentFirstLetter = left(itemTitle,1)>
    <cfif currentFirstLetter NEQ prevFirstLetter>
        <li><h2>#currentFirstLetter#</h2></li>
        <cfset prevFirstLetter = currentFirstLetter>
    </cfif>
    <!--- etc --->
</cfloop>
```

You also might benefit from reading "[When to use pound-signs](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/when-to-use-pound-signs.html)", regarding pound-sign usage.

Comment: Very clever! couldn't think of this. Thank you!